# Flex 3 - Launching a .exe file

Tags: apache-flex

i want to organize my ebooks. and want to create an air app that would have the list of my ebooks. i want it, that if i click that ebook name. i would launch/call the ebook file. just like double clicking the icon in a folder.
how could i trigger that in flex?
thanks.

also, is it possible that if i saved the page number in my flex app.when launching the ebook file, i would go directly to that particular page?:D?

thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AIR 2 you can accomplish this by using the Native Process API

Answer (score 2):

AIR does not come with the functionality to launch an external process. Your choices are to either use another EXE packaging solution (such as [MDM Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/)) or to create your own wrapper layer. Mik Chambers has a proof of concept of a [Command Proxy](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/17/commandproxy-net-air-integration-proof-of-concept/) in .NET which you could use as a basis.

If you go with the latter, the .NET class/method you will need is [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Comment: thanks. kinda complicated.:D
i was thinking. can't i just use the open method of File class of actionscript to launch a .exe file?

Comment: File.open opens the file contents as a data stream (ie. to read the contents of the file)